# Java regex to match after start of previous match

Tags: java, regex

Given a text like `abbabba`, and assuming we need to catch all occurrences of `abba` how can we do this with java regex?

Every next `matcher.find()` finds occurrence after the end of the previous match... is there a way to find next occurrence after the start of the previous match?

Comment: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(abba))");` with `matcher.find()`.